# Parse LaTeX enumerate with python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, latex

I am trying write a parser for an enumerate environment in LaTeX with python. My problem is that some of the items have enumerate environments within them and it becomes a problem to parse it. My initial approach was to get a list of all the locations of `\item` and then each location of `\begin{enumerate}` and `\end{enumerate}` and then try to write a quick algorithm for figuring out which enumerates are in which item and then pull out each item that way.

My initial approach was to use regular expressions, but I realized it get's difficult. Does anyone know a nice way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using a state machine approach?

Comment: I have not yet, any references on how I could use one for this example? Would I parse line by line, or 'word' by 'word'?

Comment: I think most articles on parsing with state machines assume that you will want to examine each and every token in the string, whereas you are really only interested in a few things that can appear. You could get by simply keeping track of where in the file you are and at each step, searching for the next instance of `\item`, `\begin{enumerate}` or `\end{enumerate}` and going to whichever is closest and proceeding as appropriate.

Comment: It would be complicated slightly if the input might contain `\item`s that do not "belong" to an enumerate environment.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try later today! If it's short and nice enough I'll post a snippit of my code here!

Comment: You should be aware of course that this will fail if the author has been "too clever" in writing their TeX code. Since any macro can expand to contain arbitrary other macros, it's quite possible for an author to frustrate you by defining a macro that expands to include `\item` or the `\begin` or `\end` commands. In which case your code will find the macro definition (unless they are especially devious and use `\csname ... \endcsname`) but not the place where `\item` etc. are actually used.